# rvm gemset with a specific ruby patch e.g. pNNN

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemset

I want to create a gemset with a specific patch version  of ruby. Generally I use

```
rvm use 2.0.0@billslim --create
```

without issue, however i need to use 2.0.0p481, but specifying p481 doesn't work e.g.

```
rvm use 2.0.0-481@billslim --create
```

and if i only use 2.0.0 it always try to install p594.

I've tried

- rvm use 2.0.0-481@billslim --create
- rvm use 2.0.0p481@billslim --create
- rvm use 2.0.0@billslim -l 481 --create
- rvm --ruby-version use 2.0.0p481  # unknown ruby string, BUT
- rvm --ruby-version use ruby-2.0.0p481 # also gives unknown ruby string
- adding a .ruby-version file in my repository root e.g. echo 'ruby-2.0.0p481' > .ruby-version
- different formats of the strings e.g. ruby-2.0.0 and ruby-2.0.0-p481 but these result in 'unknown ruby string'

nothing works...

the rvm.io docs don't seem to mention patch versions much when doing gem sets

the other info suggests patch versions should work the suggested formats don't work.

Answer (score 0):

of course the only combination i didn't try, works!

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p481@billslim --create
```

doh!